# Magento 1.9.1 Dataflow profile - import configurable products CSV

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.9.1, dataflow, configurable-product

I have a problem with CSV import of configurable products by dataflow profile.

I've created an `export.csv` with mapped fields.

Simple products associated to configurable products appear in front-end and back-end but they do not show in dropdown option (in my case size option).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code that is not working?

Comment: Here is my export.csv
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EMIQEaFi9H5qF-V7WMBMBkESmlCslU2OOLkfBDI_JZA/edit?usp=sharing

Here is default.csv
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aynQ9cQEehnbbv1LKNYSgP4akxPH05rs2U075s4oc70/edit?usp=sharing